# PhpStorm replaced vuejs separated script tag

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm

When I add a tag to a new component in the Vue.js template, PhpStorm automatically replace my separated script tag. I know you don't understand what I just wrote. Here an example of what happened.

My original `App.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <my-other-component></my-other-component>
<template>

// Note the script link to a separate Ts file.
<script src="./App.ts"></script>
```

App.ts file:

```
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component()
export default class App extends Vue {
}
```

**Everything is fine from here.**

The problem comes when I add a tag to another new component in the template, and let PhpStorm handle the import, it replace my `script` tag to this:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-class-component'
import AttributeBindingSelector from '@/components/Properties/Types/AttributeBindingSelector'
@Component({
  components: { AttributeBindingSelector }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

Note the `script` tag generated by PhpStorm replaced my `<script src="./App.ts"></script>` instead of importing the component into my `./App.ts` typescript file.

Here is a video about what is happening: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kv7R3WKToWjAlCRyGNQjm_UNlLWTezXV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: do you mean that, as soon as you add a new component tag to the `App.vue` `<template>` section, the IDE will replace your `script` tag? This doesn't happen to me. What IDE version do you use? I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching a video recording of the issue

Comment: Yes. It replace the script tag if it is linked to a file. If the typescript code is in the script tag itself in the vue template file, Phpstorm does not replace the script tag. I guess you forgot to add the Typescript code in a separate file like this: `<script src="App.ts"></script>`  I'm using PhpStorm 2020.3.2. Where to create a support ticket please?

Comment: No, I didn't forget about adding `<script src="App.ts"></script>`. To create a ticket, this use [this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731)

Comment: @lena I uploaded a video and added it to my question and also open a ticket.

Comment: Just tried repeating the issue in Vue3 +Ts project looking at your video - no luck: the `App.ts` is not updated when I choose a component from completion (as Vue3 `@Options` is not yet supported, and components aren't recognized), but the tag is not replaced

Comment: Hi, I just created a new Vuejs 2 sample project at https://github.com/Guervyl/vuejs2-phpstorm-problem. You can clone it and try to autocomplete `<new-co` then press tab or enter. It should replace the `<script>` in the App.vue.